# Where to put SQLite database to keep it from being over-ridden during update on OS X?

Tags: macos, sqlite, qt, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I'm developing my first OS X application which will be distributed through Mac App Store.

The app makes use of an sqlite database which I am currently keeping on the same location as the rest of app file dependencies.

I'm using Qt Framework to develop the application.

Keeping within the boundaries of App Store rules;

- Where can I locate the database file for it not to be overridden during app updates?
- How should I structure the .app folder and all the dependencies?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question implies that you are writing to the sqlite database, which is a bad idea given the application will be stored in a location (`/Applications`) that the user may not have write-access to.

What you should do is copy/create the database to a user-writable area (the `Documents` folder of the app's container will do) upon first use (or when you detect it's not there) and use it from there.

**EDIT**: In order to get the Documents directory use this code:

```
NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will give you the location of the app container `Documents` directory, not the user's Documents directory when the app is sandboxed:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.yourdomain.yourapp/Data/Documents
```

Comment: Hello @trojanfoe. Your guess is absolutely correct, that's what I was going to do. I thought Apple's new App Store policies required apps to be *sandboxed* without **access** to anywhere else? So basically it's safe to put db etc to a app folder created by the app in the `Documents`?

Comment: Yes, though Application Support would be a better place than Documents.

Comment: @Phil Please see my edit.  As noa points out Application Support is probably a better place, however when the app is sandboxed it has total access to its own container so I'm not sure it matters very much (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you for your extremely fast response and the recent edit, very very helpful. And thank you noa for your super fast input (4s after the comment ;-))

Comment: ~/Documents should only contain docs that the end-user would recognize  as their document (belonging to a specific app); therefore I'd suggess putting your sqlite db in the ~/Application Support/<bundle-id>/ directory.

Comment: @geowar In a sandboxed app that will be `~/Library/Containers/bundle-id/Data/Library/Application Support/bundle-id/`.

Comment: Rather than hard code the path you should use the NSSearch API:    NSString * supportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];