# Where can I store an SQLite database on Windows and OS X?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, sqlite

I'm developing a **Qt** application that will be distributed on **Windows** and **OS X**.

The application makes use of an **SQLite** database. Where can I keep the database file on both systems for it not to be overridden during application updates?

**Note 1**:
I already find a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123126/where-to-put-sqlite-database-to-keep-it-from-being-over-ridden-during-update-on) about that for **OS X**. The answer was to keep it in the `Application Support` using the following command:

```
NSString * supportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDir‌​ectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

But I need to do that on **Windows** too. Should I use this command on **Windows** too?

**Note 2**:
I'm using an INI file to store my application settings as follows:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation);
QSettings *settings = new QSettings(path+"/Settings.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
```

The `path` variable is `C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MyApplication/` (Windows).

Can I store the database file in the same path?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not? It's just a file.

Comment: I know, but is this path (`C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MyApplication/`) an appropriate location to store this kind of file?

Comment: That's up to you (I don't know what you are doing with this database), but in general, yes.

Comment: Thanks, @latedeveloper. My database stores some data collected by the user and it should "never" be deleted. Actually, I need to store this database file in some folder that the user will not accidentally delete, even using "cleaner" applications like CCleaner or any other.

Comment: In our application, we use something like note 2.  QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation) / databases

Answer (score 1):

Does `QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` cover your requirements for this?

From the [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html):

> Returns a directory location where persistent application data can be
>   stored. This is an application-specific directory. To obtain a path to
>   store data to be shared with other applications, use
>   QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation. The returned path is never empty.
>   On the Windows operating system, this returns the roaming path. This
>   enum value was added in Qt 5.4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be a great/better place to store the DB file but I'm already storing it in `QStandardPaths::ConfigLocat‌​ion`, and I'm using **Qt 5.3** and this enum was added in **Qt 5.4**.

Comment: That would make it difficult to use!